# I need to hover like this in a div with CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I created the div with flexbox and I need to do an effect like on the image when the element is hovered. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: This is done with box-shadow inset

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS box-shadow property:

```
#[here is your element name]:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-shadow` and `inset` keyword:

```
.element:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can resolved. :)

Comment: @JoaquinHernandez You're welcome, You can feel free to accept my answer.